# Convert MS Access VBA application to .NET Visual studio project

Tags: .net, visual-studio, vba, ms-access, converters

I have a  MS Access DB application with several complex forms. I want to redo this DB App in Visual Studio.Net but don't want to recreate the forms from scratch.

Is there a way to convert this application to a .NET visual Studio application?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adrian,
  You are SOL on the lack of recreation of forms.  You will HAVE to recreate the Forms, but the good note is that most of your custom methods are included in the .Net framework.

Its not like upgrading from VB6 to VB.net as the Access VBA framework is a very diluted form of VB6+ library.

You will need to have dual-monitors so you can VS design on one monitor and use the other monitor with the Access DB loaded to use as a point of reference.